# Compute method in C#

Tags: c#, datatable

can I use Compute method in future to compute two, three numbers using DataTable.Compute method?
Let's say I have a textbox containing values like: 3+3*3,

```
var dt=new DataTable();
textBox1.Text=dt.Compute(textBox1.Text,"").ToString();
```

Is this legit?

Comment: what is the expected result you want? what you want to accomplish?

Comment: Well, it works. I get number 12 when I enter this numbers

Comment: @BorisP Wasn't that a lot easier than asking us if it works? :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not forget to

1. Wrap `DataTable` into `using`.
2. Catch `EvaluateException`.

Something like this:

```
  //DONE: DataTable is IDisposable, should be wrapped into using
  using (var dt = new DataTable()) {
    try {
      textBox1.Text = dt.Compute(textBox1.Text, "").ToString();
    }
    catch (EvaluateException) {
      //TODO: Evaluation failed, put relevant code here
    }
  }
```